# Draw, Persist and Delete Balls for an Android 2D Graphics Application

Tags: java, android, graphics

Drawing some balls onto the screen that can be manipulated is simple enough (to be honest even persisting some coordinate data and re-drawing is probably not too hard)

The tricky part is that I want the user to be able to long press a given ball to delete it (Note: a restriction would probably be in place to prevent balls overlapping).

I also want to be able to persist some coordinates for these balls and load the data back in when the application is used next. At which point the user should be able to delete any ball they want, close the application and reload it to find that ball is still correctly deleted.

The balls will be drawn over the top of a background (just a simple bitmap image)

Can anyone point me in the right direction here, a suitable example would be very useful, if I am honest I thought this would be quite easy to find information about, but it is actually quite tough.

Thanks for your time.